# Why am I not promoted even though I'm the only guy in charge?

Tags: promotion

I have had a couple of experiences where I was the only guy in a department / team. Automatically, this made me the leader.

I even revolutionized a department once.

However, people above me in the hierarchy, want me to continue doing what I do, and then hire somebody, a junior for instance, make us feel as we are on the same level.

Recently, I have been working on a project where I quickly learned the technology and became productive. I was supposed to work with an N + 2, the level of a software architect who was supposed to contribute with a capacity of 20%. But he never participated. All his meeting invitations were replied with tentative, and never attended.

A manager from Spain (I work for a nearshore company) provided a professional briefing, stating I was the team leader, and that they rely on me to build a new team locally so that they could export work. However, my local manager hid this information and kept piling on tasks. I found myself doing the work of at least two if not three people.

The manager from Spain once asked me to show him what I was doing and stated that he was happy with the work, but the workload was too much for me.

He spoke to my local manager, who assigned me two junior employees I was supposed to supervise. That was an opportunity for me to bring to the table the topic of my promotion. In fact, all the colleagues I know have been promoted. I helped colleagues who were frequently blocked get promoted while I was not.

I don't want to brag or anything, but I've solved serious complex problems, but management has always behaved in such a way as if I was doing regular work and never communicated the congratulations by intermediate or final clients.

Whenever I brought up the topic to my local manager, he'd get furious and refuse to even discuss it despite the fact I clarified all the doubts regarding the projects, took the initiative and negotiated a remote machine + OS, and settled down infrastructure and the architecture, and the project started to look doable.

So, I had to do development work, negotiate for hardware, speak to clients, manage a team, and train new people, write documentation… I am a "senior" developer, and the next level is team leader or technical leader.

Clearly, I was doing technical leader work.

My interlocutors from Spain themselves were technical leaders, and treated me as such.

Why is it that although I do such a great job and provide concrete results, my managers pretend I don't do much and don't even encourage me?

Why don't top manager intervene to fix such situations when it is still fixable?

PS: they know it's very hard to find someone who can work so eagerly and able to make projects succeed.

I have been absent for more than one month, and I sent them back their laptop, and now I am working on my resignation and stuff, but they didn't delete my account nor anything.

As a matter of fact, last had, I had a similar depressing situation that costed me 3 / 4 months of medical leave, and they suggested a different project to convince me to come back.

The situation of the company is that they have a high turn over, and it looks like it's full of junior developer who leave as soon as they gain a little of experience.

They need this solid core of Senior / Leader developers that seems to be floatant.

A decade ago, I faced a similar situation in a different company where I was not happy, I was planning to leave, they brought an HR girl who sat with me and told me nice things, such I am appreciated and they don't want me to leave.

They didn't fix anything, and now, the company is struggling and they keep losing good people and they fail to transcend.

Comment: So, take your experience and find a better post. Even if they admit to anything, what makes you think they will change? They get you for cheap so why pay you more now??

Comment: Very often the answer to "Why do people treat me like this?" is "Because you let them".

Comment: "they know it's very hard to find someone who can work so eagerly and able to make projects succeed." - You could always challenge them to this task.  Of course I don't recommend you do that, since i suspect, you will be shocked at how quickly they could replace you.  They might replace you with somebody they might regret later, but everyone can be replaced, except maybe the one guy in the world that knows how to make [Pule donkey cheese](https://www.businessinsider.com/why-pule-donkey-cheese-serbia-most-expensive-in-the-world-2021-3)

Comment: Brush up your CV and start sending it for various interesting positions. Trough interviews and eventual job offerings from other companies you will realize your worth on the market. Maybe you are underpaid at your current job, but it is also possible that currently you are not worth much more .

Comment: In my country, people don't value competence: they value relationships, connections etc. They hire competent people only when they are in trouble and throw them like used towels when they're done with them, to the attribute the success to themselves.
Recently, it feels like something is changing and people without competence are getting more and more in trouble.

Comment: In my country, you need to lie during the interview, to look confident. When you're a geek, they know you must be good in the computer programming stuff, but they don't like the fact that you are direct, shy, or lack the social skill to duly impress. "I won't hire him, he didn't even try to impress me". Look at the job interview in the first minue of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mnjx-Konjxk

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you're a great software developer.

- "I fastly learned the technology and became productive."
- You did the job of the software architect, who ghosted you.
- "I took the initiative and negociated a remote machine + OS, and settled down infrastructure and the architecture, and the project started to look doable."

Your understanding of career development seems odd.

- "[...] I was the only guy in a department / team. Automatically, this makes of me the leader." I have to disagree here. Working alone is rarely counted as leadership.
- "I am a 'senior' developer, and the next level is team leader or technical leader." Again, I have to disagree. It is not at all common to get promoted to management. There aren't enough management jobs for this to be true.

Unfortunately it also sounds like you're not a good leader.

- The software architect ghosted you and you didn't find any solution besides doing the work yourself. If you become a team lead you will regularly face the situation that somebody who should work on your project got other priorities. So better learn to fix it.
- Although you solved a complex technical problem, your manager got furious and didn't want to talk with you about it. Of course your boss could be a jerk, but it doesn't sound like you understand why and what happened. What will you do if you've got this situation with somebody that reports to you or again somebody above you?

Don't give up. Leadership skills can be learned, if you're willing to change your behaviour and are able to let go your previous technical role. Don't let you be forced into management just because others are moving there. Maybe becoming a technical expert is a better fit for you.

Comment: Thank you for the interaction. I described the situation as it is, but I dismissed many aspects: I know the software architect is protected by other managers. My intention was to move forward to make concrete results and apply my coup. Instead of complaining. The project manager would tell me "the architect is not responding, why is that? he doesn't even care about us", for me this was an act because behind the scenes, something is not right.

Comment: at the end of 2019, a manager came to me and told me that my (previous) teamleader lied about the imputation. He mentioned that he worked on DEV tasks rather than MNG tasks for a certain project. The interpretation of these data in the other end would be interpreted very negatively about me. This manager knows I did all the work, as he knows the teamleader didn't write a line of code at all.